# Pro Core Data book, example code question

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm learning Core Data with the help of the book. There is a code:

```
- (void)loadData {
// Pull the movies. If we have 200, assume our db is set up.
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Movie"
                               inManagedObjectContext:context]];
NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
if ([results count] != 200) {
// Add 200 actors, movies, and studios
for (int i = 1; i <= 200; i++) {
[self insertObjectForName:@"Actor" withName:
                 [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Actor %d", i]];
[self insertObjectForName:@"Movie" withName:
                 [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Movie %d", i]];
[self insertObjectForName:@"Studio" withName:
                 [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Studio %d", i]];
}
// Relate all the actors and all the studios to all the movies
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Movie"
                               inManagedObjectContext:context]];
NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
for (NSManagedObject *movie in results) {
[request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Actor"
                               inManagedObjectContext:context]];
NSArray *actors = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
NSMutableSet *set = [movie mutableSetValueForKey:@"actors"];
[set addObjectsFromArray:actors];
[request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Studio"
                               inManagedObjectContext:context]];
NSArray *studios = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
set = [movie mutableSetValueForKey:@"studios"];
[set addObjectsFromArray:studios];
}
}
[request release];
NSError *error = nil;
if (![context save:&error]) {
NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
abort();
}
}
```

The main question is: is it necessary to renew the context pointer, if there were any changes in that context? 
What I mean: I get the pointer to the context at the beginning of the method, next in the loop I take this context and insert managed objects there (-insertObjectForName:withName:). Then I see this renewal of the context pointer and have that question: is it a rule of some kind, and I should act the same, or its just not-so-neat code example? Why can't I use the old pointer?

---Edit--- One more question: is that a legal initialization of a request here in the code:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
...
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
...
[request release];
```

Two allocs and only one release?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also have this book and looked it up.

Clearly seems like a typo to me and doesn't really make much sense.

Just ignore that line and continue - it should work fine without.

Comment: Then, should I recreate the request and a result array? Or they'll be fine with old pointers?

Comment: I just downloaded the source code from the book website and removed those lines. It does not have an impact on the app. It might just be a typo..

Comment: There's also no errata posted on that book yet... http://www.apress.com/9781430233558

Comment: So, to clarify that moment about the request and results array: should I fire the request once more to get the new results array? And does the request is intact till its release? So I can call '[context executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];' with the old inited pointer?

Comment: Yes, yo can freely use the same request again. It will only be discarded once it's released - you can use it as often as you want until then.

Comment: I've reorganized the code to use the old pointers, to the request and to the results array, and it worked like charm. Thanks. :)

Comment: great to hear that :-)! - please mark the matching answer as accepted for the next one stumbling upon this.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion

> its just not-so-neat code example

About your second question: There have to also two releases! Otherwise you have a leak.

Comment: Yeah, I tend to think so. I have a lot of questions to their codes, but I consider the fact that memory management and other aspects of programming - are not the purpose of this book. There are no questions to the Core Data matters. :)

Answer (score 0):

That's some seriously ugly code.

This:

NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

... is probably just because they want to be able to write `context` in a method call instead of `self.managedObjectContext`.

Using:
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

... twice is allowed but it is lazy bad practice. Any variable should be named only once in a scope. In fact, the compiler will generate a warning with this code. It will leak because every `init` must be balanced by a `release`.

Comment: Thank you. I feel the same. :)